in android studio panoramagl ican't display the panorama image?
 public void vr() {
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_vr);
        PLManager plManager = new PLManager(MainActivity.this);
        plManager.setContentView(R.layout.fragment_vr);
        PLSphericalPanorama panorama = new PLSphericalPanorama();
        panorama.getCamera().lookAt(30.0f, 90.0f);

        panorama.setImage(new PLImage(PLUtils.getBitmap(MainActivity.this, R.raw.room_vr), false));
        plManager.setPanorama(panorama);
    }

when i try to load the R.layout.fragment_vr it says
Required type:
ViewGroup
Provided:
int
then tried this
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
ViewGroup contentView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_vr, null);
plManager.setContentView(contentView);
and i get this error                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.panoramagl.PLManager.onGLSurfaceViewCreated(PLManager.kt:1393)
